# Running a QT gui from docker

Tags: docker, qt, x11

I am trying to dockerize and run a QT-based application which spawns a windowed app and pass it to my Ubuntu machine.
What I have so far is :

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:xenial-20210804
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \ 
     apt update && apt install software-properties-common -y && \
     apt-add-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt591-xenial
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt,sharing=locked \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/var/lib/apt,sharing=locked \ 
     apt update && \
     apt-get install git cmake qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev qt59multimedia qt59quickcontrols \ 
     qt59imageformats qt59quickcontrols2 qt59script libfftw3-dev libsamplerate0-dev \ 
     libasound2-dev libmpv-dev libdrm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev portaudio19-dev autoconf libtool xvfb -y 
RUN mkdir build && cd build
RUN git clone https://github.com/thestk/rtmidi            # build & install
RUN cd rtmidi && git checkout 88e53b9 && ./autogen.sh && make && make install
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN cd /app/build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/qt59/ && make -j8
# RUN rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so && ldconfig
# RUN Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/build/appname"] # This binary launches the app.
# -- Below this line is things I've tried without success
# ENV DISPLAY=:1
# RUN groupadd -g 1000 myuser
# RUN useradd -d /home/myuser -s /bin/bash -m myuser -u 1000 -g 1000
# USER myuser
# ENV HOME /home/myuser
```

Running this with

```
sudo docker build -t app_img .
```

and running

```
 sudo docker run --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY --net=host app_img
```

produces

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Could not initialize GLX
```

I tried resolving the above according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834254/steam-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl-error-failed-t) but with no luck

---

I've also tried running with `sudo docker run --volume="$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw" --net=host rad_lib`

but I get

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

At this point I have no idea how to proceed. I am not really well versed (or at all) in QT things or producing guis from dockerfiles. Any input or direction would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anyone is interested, I was able to somewhat launch the app using:

`Dockerfile`

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu16.04
# FROM ubuntu:xenial-20210804
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN apt update && apt install software-properties-common -y && \
     apt-add-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt591-xenial
RUN  apt update && \
     apt-get install git cmake qt59base qt59declarative qt59multimedia qt59quickcontrols \ 
     qt59imageformats qt59graphicaleffects qt59quickcontrols2 qt59script libfftw3-dev libsamplerate0-dev \ 
     libasound2-dev libmpv-dev libdrm-dev libgl1-mesa-dev portaudio19-dev autoconf libtool xvfb alsa-tools \ 
     alsa-utils libsndfile1-dev -y 
RUN git submodule update --init
RUN mkdir build && cd build
RUN git clone https://github.com/thestk/rtmidi            # build & install
RUN cd rtmidi && git checkout 88e53b9 && ./autogen.sh && make && make install
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN cd /app/build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/qt59/ && make -j$(($(nproc) - 1))
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/build/radiance"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: rad_lib2
    build: .
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
    devices:
      - /dev/snd:/dev/snd
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
      - QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
      - QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
      - QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/qt59/plugins
      - QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/qt59/plugins
      - XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
      - ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority
    network_mode: "host"
```

You can (maybe) test this from my [fork](https://github.com/iakovts/radiance/tree/dockerfile_supp) of the Radiance project.

---

This is a very rough solution, as I've used the nvidia opengl implementation so this is probably limited to systems with nvidia gpus. Also there are issues with stability, as the app will run but it will crash when in foreground and fullscreen. No issues if you have another window on it. Anyway, I guess it could serve as a starting point for someone looking to launch a QT application through docker.